# After installing Alfresco PDF Toolkit, Alfresco fail to start

Tags: java, pdf, alfresco, alfresco-share, toolkit

I tried the followings but fail to find a way to make Alfresco PDF Toolkit works.

I am planning to use either Alfresco community 4.2e or 5.0d and I want to add the Alfresco PDF Toolkit in it.

I use the AMPs provided in the website. It said it support Alfresco 4.x to 5.x 
I install the amps by `apply_amps` command.

---

I successfully installed Alfresco PDF Toolkit 1.2 on 4.2e, but Alfresco fail to start after.
I failed to install Alfresco PDF Toolkit 1.3 on 4.2e.
I successfully installed Alfresco PDF Toolkit 1.2 on 5.0d, but Alfresco fail to start after.
I successfully installed Alfresco PDF Toolkit 1.3 on 5.0d, but Alfresco fail to start after.

The fail to start error is the same and is listed below:

```
2015-12-18 14:29:58,041 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pdf-convert-to-archivable' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/org.alfresco.extension.pdftoolkit/context/alfresco-pdf-toolkit-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/artofsolving/jodconverter/document/DocumentFormatRegistry
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
 at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/artofsolving/jodconverter/document/DocumentFormatRegistry
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1031)
 ... 27 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.document.DocumentFormatRegistry
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
 ... 33 more
```

Is it possible that I need to install additional component or else?

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try to check in your file `alfresco-pdf-toolkit-context.xml` there is a class named: `DocumentFormatRegistry`

Comment: Seems like it is having dependancy on this jodconverter  jar. Download and add it in your lib folder. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjodconvertercore30beta3sourcesjar.htm

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? The steps you followed are not clear. Have you tried to install on the same installation of Alfresco different versions of the same extension?